# Auto Select First Dropdown Option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on this codes: http://jsfiddle.net/3UWk2/3/

```
<select size="1" id="Rank" title="" name="Rank">
<option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
<option value="airman">Airman</option>
<option value="senior-airman">Senior Airman</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
<div class="airman">
    <select class="second-level-select">
        <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
        <option value="basic-ore-1">Basic Ore Miner - Level 1</option>
        <option value="basic-ore-2">Basic Ore Miner - Level 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="senior-airman">
    <select class="second-level-select">
        <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
        <option value="omber-miner-1">Omber Miner - Level 1</option>
        <option value="omber-miner-2">Omber Miner - Level 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>

<div class="second-level-container">
<div class="basic-ore-1">
    Line of text for basic ore miner 1
</div>
<div class="basic-ore-2">
    Line of text for basic ore miner 2
</div>
<div class="omber-miner-1">
    Line of text for omber miner 1
</div>
<div class="omber-miner-2">
    Line of text for omber miner 2
</div>    
</div>
```

Followed By:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Rank').bind('change', function() {
    var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
        elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
    }
}).trigger('change');

$('.second-level-select').bind('change', function() {
    var elements = $('div.second-level-container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
        elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
    }
}).trigger('change');
});
```

How do I auto select the first option of both dropdown and display the final value OnLoad?

I'm looking at 3 by 3 drop down, with 9 values in total.

Comment: couldnt get "display final value onLoad" part , you want same solution with 3 dropdowns and you want the first option of both the drop downs to be selected automatically on page load and the related line text ?

Comment: I want the first option of both dropdown to be automatically selected and final value to be displayed.

Also after selection, changing the 1st drop down does not affect the final value until 2nd dropdown is selected again, any way to work around this?

Thanks for your prompt reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this might help you out

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//bind onchange for the rank dd
  $("#Rank").on('change', function() {
    let selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $(".container>div").hide();
    if (selectedValue.length) {
      $("." + selectedValue).show();
      //select.val($(select + " option:eq(1)").val());
    }
  })
//bind onchange for the airman dd
  $("#second-level-select-airman").on('change', function() {
    let selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $(".second-level-container").children().hide();


    if (selectedValue.length) {
      $("." + selectedValue).show();
      //select.val($(select + " option:eq(1)").val());
    }
  })
//bind onchange for the senior airman
  $("#second-level-select-senior-airman").on('change', function() {
    let selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $(".second-level-container").children().hide();


    if (selectedValue.length) {
      $("." + selectedValue).show();
      //select.val($(select + " option:eq(1)").val());
    }
  });
  //select first value of first dropdown
  $("#Rank").val($("#Rank option:eq(1)").val()).trigger('change');
  
  //select the first option from the 2nd menu depending on the valur of the first dd
  $("." + $("#Rank").val()).find("select").val(
    $("." + $("#Rank").val()).find("select option:eq(1)").val()
  ).trigger('change');
  // $("#Rank").val($("#Rank option:eq(1)").val());
  // $("." + $("#Rank").val()).find("select").val(
  //     $("." + $("#Rank").val()).find("select option:eq(1)").val()
  // );
});
```

```css
.airman,
.senior-airman,
.second-level-container>div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Rank" name="Rank">
            <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
            <option value="airman">Airman</option>
            <option value="senior-airman">Senior Airman</option>
        </select>

<div class="container">
  <div class="airman">
    <select class="second-level-select" id="second-level-select-airman">
                    <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
                    <option value="basic-ore-1">Basic Ore Miner - Level 1</option>
                    <option value="basic-ore-2">Basic Ore Miner - Level 2</option>
                </select>
  </div>
  <div class="senior-airman">
    <select class="second-level-select" id="second-level-select-senior-airman">
                    <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
                    <option value="omber-miner-1">Omber Miner - Level 1</option>
                    <option value="omber-miner-2">Omber Miner - Level 2</option>
                </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second-level-container">
  <div class="basic-ore-1">
    Line of text for basic ore miner 1
  </div>
  <div class="basic-ore-2">
    Line of text for basic ore miner 2
  </div>
  <div class="omber-miner-1">
    Line of text for omber miner 1
  </div>
  <div class="omber-miner-2">
    Line of text for omber miner 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works great!

However after selecting both dropdown with the value displayed, if user were to change the first drop down, the value does not change. Any way to work around it?

Comment: do select the correct answer if it works for you so that others looking for same solution can also get benefit @Jacky

Comment: Okay but could you help me solve the part on my previous comment? also it doesn't seems to display correctly on mobile

Comment: it is doing what you wanted ,

first option of both dropdown automatically selected and final value displayed. 
after selection, changing the 1st drop down does not affect the final value until 2nd dropdown is selected again.

dont know about the display on mobile might be related to the css issue, this post was for the auto selection of dropdowns, you can create a separate post and add you html css code that is used and the output you are reciveing on mobile in form of screen shot